# (Python) How to download an image from a link that generates via javascript?

Tags: python-2.7

Basically, I want to be able to download the png at the bottom of a page like [this one (link)](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Home/RegionalDroughtMonitor.aspx?west). The site generates the link to the png through a javascript function, from what I can tell.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We encourage users to post what they already tried, as well as the bit of code that isn't working well for you in the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to try to be honest, and nothing I found online was what I was looking for

Comment: which png are you trying to grab?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to fetch the most recent date listed in [the parent directory](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/data/pngs/), then for the next part of the URL check the links listed on the page for that date ([example](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/data/pngs/20170221/)) for a string ending with whatever you're looking for; so for Drought Monitor West, that'd be a link ending in *_west_trd.png*.